# Howto convert a Shadertoy shader to a pixijs v6 shader/filter

Tags: pixi.js

i need help to convert a shadertoy filter (https://www.shadertoy.com/view/7tsfWS) to newest pixijs version filter.

Somehow my canvas stays black and i dont know what i do wrong.

I prepared sth on pixiplayground: https://www.pixiplayground.com/#/edit/av3kcgJuH2ISiPpSmz4uI

Thx already in advance for the help

Comment: Related: https://codepen.io/alaingalvan/pen/gOoEpW , https://www.shadertoy.com/view/Xsl3Dl , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75209607/filter-shader-godrays-which-does-not-darken-the-background

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in how you are passing the uniform values to the shader. It's fixed by removing the wrapping object:

```js
var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;
const uniforms = {
    iResolution: [width, height],
    iTime: 0
};
```

As you can see in the [examples](https://pixijs.io/examples/?v=v6.1.3#/filters-advanced/custom.js), in PIXI version 5 and above you don't need to declare the uniforms in objects with `type` and `value`. This can also be found in the [migration guide](https://github.com/pixijs/pixijs/wiki/v4-Migration-Guide#filters).