# Filter/Shader "Godrays" which does not darken the background

Tags: background, shader, transparency, pixi.js, light

Dear Magnificent Community and Developers,

There's a [PixiJs](https://pixijs.com/) filter which is based on a shader "["Godrays" by alaingalvan](https://codepen.io/alaingalvan/pen/gOoEpW)", but it is required to somehow achieve such a filter/shader which does lighten certain areas where "lights" exist on a transparent stage without darkening the background.

The [current version](https://codepen.io/faither/pen/wvxqRPo) creates dark places ('0x000000') where the "lights" are not shown, but the darkness must not surpass the background ('0x333333' or '0xffffff' as in CSS), so it would look like a transparent filter in the result. This is the incorrect behavior since it creates black background where the "lights" are (it is correct that it affects the background):

[image: ...]

---

```js
const uniformData = {
    time: {
        type: 'float',
        value: 0.0
    },
    lacunarity: {
        type: 'float',
        value: 30.0
    },
    gain: {
        type: 'float',
        value: 1.0
    },
    parallel: {
        type: 'b',
        value: true
    },
    light: {
        type: 'v2',
        value: [0.0, 0.0]
    },
    dimensions: {
        type: 'v2',
        value: [800, 400]
    },
    aspect: {
        type: 'float',
        value: 1.0
    }
};

// 3D gradient Noise
// MIT License
// Copyright © 2013 Inigo Quilez
// https://www.shadertoy.com/view/Xsl3Dl

// Original: https://codepen.io/alaingalvan/pen/gOoEpW

const fragSource = '' +
    `precision mediump float;

varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
uniform sampler2D uSampler;
uniform vec4 filterArea;
uniform vec2 dimensions;

uniform vec2 light;
uniform bool parallel;
uniform float aspect;

uniform float gain;
uniform float lacunarity;
uniform float time;

vec3 hash(vec3 p) {
    p = vec3(
        dot(p, vec3(127.1, 311.7, 74.7)),
        dot(p, vec3(269.5, 183.3, 246.1)),
        dot(p, vec3(113.5, 271.9, 124.6))
    );

    return -1.0 + 2.0 * fract(sin(p) * 43758.5453123);
}

float noise(in vec3 p) {
    vec3 i = floor(p);
    vec3 f = fract(p);
    vec3 u = f * f * (3.0 - 2.0 * f);

    return mix(
        mix(
            mix(
                dot(hash(i + vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)), f - vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)),
                dot(hash(i + vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)), f - vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)),
                u.x
            ),
            mix(
                dot(hash(i + vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)), f - vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)),
                dot(hash(i + vec3(1.0, 1.0, 0.0)), f - vec3(1.0, 1.0, 0.0)),
                u.x
            ),
            u.y
        ),
        mix(
            mix(
                dot(hash(i + vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)), f - vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)),
                dot(hash(i + vec3(1.0, 0.0, 1.0)), f - vec3(1.0, 0.0, 1.0)),
                u.x
            ),
            mix(
                dot(hash(i + vec3(0.0, 1.0, 1.0)), f - vec3(0.0, 1.0, 1.0)),
                dot(hash(i + vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)), f - vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)),
                u.x
            ),
            u.y
        ),
        u.z
    );
}

float turb(vec3 pos, float lacunarity, float gain) {
    float f, totalGain;
    totalGain = gain;
    vec3 q = 2.0 * pos;
    f = totalGain * noise(q);

    q = q * 2.01 * lacunarity;
    totalGain *= gain;
    f += totalGain * noise(q);

    q = q * 3.02 * lacunarity;
    totalGain *= gain;
    f += totalGain * noise(q);

    q = q * 3.03 * lacunarity;
    totalGain *= gain;
    f += totalGain * noise(q);

    q = q * 3.01 * lacunarity;
    totalGain *= gain;
    f += totalGain * noise(q);

    q = q * 3.99 * lacunarity;
    totalGain *= gain;
    f += totalGain * noise(q);

    q = q * 3.98 * lacunarity;
    totalGain *= gain;
    f += totalGain * noise(q);
    f = 3.0 * f;

    return abs(f);
}

void main(void) {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(uSampler, vTextureCoord);
    float d = 0.0;
    vec2 coord = vTextureCoord;

    if (parallel) {
        float _cos = light.x;
        float _sin = light.y;
        d = (_cos * coord.x) + (_sin * coord.y * aspect);
    } else {
        float dx = coord.x - light.x / dimensions.x;
        float dy = (coord.y - light.y / dimensions.y) * aspect;
        float dis = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) + 0.00001;
        d = dy / dis;
    }

    vec2 dir = vec2(d, d);
    float noise = turb(vec3(dir, 0.0) + vec3(time, 0.0, 62.1 + time) * 0.1, lacunarity, gain);
    vec4 mist = vec4(noise, noise, noise, 1.0);
    noise = mix(noise, 0.0, 0.3);
    mist *= 1.0 - coord.y;
    mist = clamp(mist, 0.0, 1.0);

    gl_FragColor += mist;
}`;

class Rays extends PIXI.Filter
{
    _options = {
        angle: 30,
        lacunarity: 1.5,
        gain: 0.4,
        parallel: Math.round(Math.random()),
        speed: 0.0003
    }

    _timeInit = null;

    constructor()
    {
        super(null, fragSource, uniformData);
        this._timeInit = Date.now() - Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999999);
    }

    apply(filterManager, input, output, clearMode, _currentState)
    {
        this.uniforms.time = (Date.now() - this._timeInit) * this._options.speed;
        this.uniforms.lacunarity = this._options.lacunarity;
        this.uniforms.gain = this._options.gain;
        this.uniforms.parallel = this._options.parallel;

        const radians = this._options.angle * Math.PI / 180.0;
        this.uniforms.light[0] = Math.cos(radians);
        this.uniforms.light[1] = Math.sin(radians);

        const {width, height} = input.filterFrame;
        this.uniforms.dimensions[0] = width;
        this.uniforms.dimensions[1] = height;
        this.uniforms.aspect = height / width;

        filterManager.applyFilter(this, input, output, clearMode);
    }
}

// -------------------------------

class App
{
    _app = null;
    
    _resources = null;
    
    constructor() {
        this._app = new PIXI.Application({
            view: canvas,
            width: 800,
            height: 600,
            transparent: true,
            resolution: window.devicePixelRatio
        });
        
        this._init();
    }
    
    addRelativeFeather(x, y) {
        const feather = new PIXI.Sprite(this._resources.feather.texture);
        
        const scale = Math.max(
            this._app.screen.width / (feather.width * 3),
            this._app.screen.height / (feather.height * 3)
        );
            
        feather.scale.set(scale, scale);
        feather.position.set(x * feather.width, y * feather.height);
        feather.filters = [new Rays()];
        this._app.stage.addChild(feather);
    }
    
    _main() {
        this.addRelativeFeather(0, 0);
        this.addRelativeFeather(1, 0);
        this.addRelativeFeather(2, 0);
        this.addRelativeFeather(0, 1);
        this.addRelativeFeather(2, 1);
    }
    
    _init() {
        const loader = PIXI.Loader.shared;

        loader.add({
            name: 'feather',
            // Icon "feather": https://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/feathers_6981026
            url: 'https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/6981/6981026.png',
        });

        loader.onComplete.once((loaderProcessed, resources) => {
            this._resources = resources;
            this._main();
        });
        
        loader.load();
    }
}

const app = new App();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://pixijs.download/v6.5.8/pixi.js"></script>

<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

---

Is it possible using this filter/shader? Is it correct that the issue is in the color matrix ("float noise(in vec3 p)")?

Also, it's probably the `mist = clamp(mist, 0.0, 1.0);` where the second parameter might assume the minimum allowed if that makes sense.

Would it be correct to somehow base a pixel color on the source and only increase its "gain" instead?

I would highly appreciate any suggestion since I have already tried various options but it still darkens the origin!

Best and kind regards ✨

Comment: do you tried contacting author of this shader? (on github or where you found it etc)

Comment: I didn't, dear @domis86 . Considering the code's copyright notice, it was written in 2013, so... I chose to not bother the author after 10 years of their wonderful share ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const uniformData = {
    time: {
        type: 'float',
        value: 0.0
    },
    lacunarity: {
        type: 'float',
        value: 30.0
    },
    gain: {
        type: 'float',
        value: 1.0
    },
    parallel: {
        type: 'b',
        value: true
    },
    light: {
        type: 'v2',
        value: [0.0, 0.0]
    },
    dimensions: {
        type: 'v2',
        value: [800, 400]
    },
    aspect: {
        type: 'float',
        value: 1.0
    }
};

// 3D gradient Noise
// MIT License
// Copyright © 2013 Inigo Quilez
// https://www.shadertoy.com/view/Xsl3Dl

// Original: https://codepen.io/alaingalvan/pen/gOoEpW

const fragSource = '' +
    `precision mediump float;

varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
uniform sampler2D uSampler;
uniform vec4 filterArea;
uniform vec2 dimensions;

uniform vec2 light;
uniform bool parallel;
uniform float aspect;

uniform float gain;
uniform float lacunarity;
uniform float time;

vec3 hash(vec3 p) {
    p = vec3(
        dot(p, vec3(127.1, 311.7, 74.7)),
        dot(p, vec3(269.5, 183.3, 246.1)),
        dot(p, vec3(113.5, 271.9, 124.6))
    );

    return -1.0 + 2.0 * fract(sin(p) * 43758.5453123);
}

float noise(in vec3 p) {
    vec3 i = floor(p);
    vec3 f = fract(p);
    vec3 u = f * f * (3.0 - 2.0 * f);

    return mix(
        mix(
            mix(
                dot(hash(i + vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)), f - vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)),
                dot(hash(i + vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)), f - vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)),
                u.x
            ),
            mix(
                dot(hash(i + vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)), f - vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)),
                dot(hash(i + vec3(1.0, 1.0, 0.0)), f - vec3(1.0, 1.0, 0.0)),
                u.x
            ),
            u.y
        ),
        mix(
            mix(
                dot(hash(i + vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)), f - vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)),
                dot(hash(i + vec3(1.0, 0.0, 1.0)), f - vec3(1.0, 0.0, 1.0)),
                u.x
            ),
            mix(
                dot(hash(i + vec3(0.0, 1.0, 1.0)), f - vec3(0.0, 1.0, 1.0)),
                dot(hash(i + vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)), f - vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)),
                u.x
            ),
            u.y
        ),
        u.z
    );
}

float turb(vec3 pos, float lacunarity, float gain) {
    float f, totalGain;
    totalGain = gain;
    vec3 q = 2.0 * pos;
    f = totalGain * noise(q);

    q = q * 2.01 * lacunarity;
    totalGain *= gain;
    f += totalGain * noise(q);

    q = q * 3.02 * lacunarity;
    totalGain *= gain;
    f += totalGain * noise(q);

    q = q * 3.03 * lacunarity;
    totalGain *= gain;
    f += totalGain * noise(q);

    q = q * 3.01 * lacunarity;
    totalGain *= gain;
    f += totalGain * noise(q);

    q = q * 3.99 * lacunarity;
    totalGain *= gain;
    f += totalGain * noise(q);

    q = q * 3.98 * lacunarity;
    totalGain *= gain;
    f += totalGain * noise(q);
    f = 3.0 * f;

    return abs(f);
}

void main(void) {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(uSampler, vTextureCoord);
    float d = 0.0;
    vec2 coord = vTextureCoord;

    if (parallel) {
        float _cos = light.x;
        float _sin = light.y;
        d = (_cos * coord.x) + (_sin * coord.y * aspect);
    } else {
        float dx = coord.x - light.x / dimensions.x;
        float dy = (coord.y - light.y / dimensions.y) * aspect;
        float dis = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) + 0.00001;
        d = dy / dis;
    }

    vec2 dir = vec2(d, d);
    float noise = turb(vec3(dir, 0.0) + vec3(time, 0.0, 62.1 + time) * 0.1, lacunarity, gain);
    vec4 mist = vec4(noise, noise, noise, noise);
    noise = mix(noise, 0.0, 0.3);
    mist *= 1.0 - coord.y;
    mist = clamp(mist, 0.0, 1.0);

    gl_FragColor += mist;
}`;

class Rays extends PIXI.Filter
{
    _options = {
        angle: 30,
        lacunarity: 1.5,
        gain: 0.4,
        parallel: Math.round(Math.random()),
        speed: 0.0003
    }

    _timeInit = null;

    constructor()
    {
        super(null, fragSource, uniformData);
        this._timeInit = Date.now() - Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999999);
    }

    apply(filterManager, input, output, clearMode, _currentState)
    {
        this.uniforms.time = (Date.now() - this._timeInit) * this._options.speed;
        this.uniforms.lacunarity = this._options.lacunarity;
        this.uniforms.gain = this._options.gain;
        this.uniforms.parallel = this._options.parallel;

        const radians = this._options.angle * Math.PI / 180.0;
        this.uniforms.light[0] = Math.cos(radians);
        this.uniforms.light[1] = Math.sin(radians);

        const {width, height} = input.filterFrame;
        this.uniforms.dimensions[0] = width;
        this.uniforms.dimensions[1] = height;
        this.uniforms.aspect = height / width;

        filterManager.applyFilter(this, input, output, clearMode);
    }
}

// -------------------------------

class App
{
    _app = null;
    
    _resources = null;
    
    constructor() {
        this._app = new PIXI.Application({
            view: canvas,
            width: 800,
            height: 600,
            transparent: true,
            resolution: window.devicePixelRatio
        });
        
        this._init();
    }
    
    addRelativeFeather(x, y) {
        const feather = new PIXI.Sprite(this._resources.feather.texture);
        
        const scale = Math.max(
            this._app.screen.width / (feather.width * 3),
            this._app.screen.height / (feather.height * 3)
        );
            
        feather.scale.set(scale, scale);
        feather.position.set(x * feather.width, y * feather.height);
        feather.filters = [new Rays()];
        this._app.stage.addChild(feather);
    }
    
    _main() {
        this.addRelativeFeather(0, 0);
        this.addRelativeFeather(1, 0);
        this.addRelativeFeather(2, 0);
        this.addRelativeFeather(0, 1);
        this.addRelativeFeather(2, 1);
    }
    
    _init() {
        const loader = PIXI.Loader.shared;

        loader.add({
            name: 'feather',
            // Icon "feather": https://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/feathers_6981026
            url: 'https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/6981/6981026.png',
        });

        loader.onComplete.once((loaderProcessed, resources) => {
            this._resources = resources;
            this._main();
        });
        
        loader.load();
    }
}

const app = new App();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://pixijs.download/v6.5.8/pixi.js"></script>

<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

The shader defines the following vec4 for painting with hardcoded 1.0 alpha:

```
vec4 mist = vec4(noise, noise, noise, 1.0);
```

Use the whiteness of the noise value as alpha as following to get rid of the black background:

```
vec4 mist = vec4(noise, noise, noise, noise);
```

Comment: Oh... my... dear... How did I miss... Thank you very much, dear @Eduardo! Please have a pleasant time and stay safe! ✨